# Accessing an array of tuples Swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift, tuples, core-location

I am trying to assign values to certain components of a custom collection view cell. The array is in the same class as the custom collection view cell yet I can't seam to access the array. any advice would be appreciated.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
class eventCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet private weak var eventTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private weak var descriptionLabel:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private weak var eventImage: UIImageView!

    var eventArray = [(title:String, location:String, lat:CLLocationDegrees, long:CLLocationDegrees)]()   

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        eventImage.image = nil
    }

    func lool() {
        eventTitle.text = eventArray.title
    }
}
```

Yet I keep getting this error when I try to add a title:

> Value of type '[(title: String, location: String, lat: CLLocationDegrees, long: CLLocationDegrees)]' (aka 'Array<(title: String, location: String, lat: Double, long: Double)>') has no member 'title'

Any help would be great, thanks in advance!

Comment: `eventArray` is array, so if you want to access title than try `eventArray[index].title`

Comment: Exactly, to a single event cell you should add only a single event, not the whole array of events.

Comment: @Sulthan but what about if I wanted to loop through all of the events in the array? How would I do that?

Comment: @RoryRozzerHodgson That's what the `UICollectionView` does.

Comment: Ahh okay, I’ll try that now, sorry for asking noob questions haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
class eventCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet private weak var eventTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private weak var descriptionLabel:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private weak var eventImage: UIImageView!

    typealias Event = (title:String, location:String, lat:CLLocationDegrees, long:CLLocationDegrees)

    var eventArray = [Event]()


    override func prepareForReuse() {
        eventImage.image = nil
    }

    func lool() {
        var event = Event(title: "a", location:"b", lat:5, long:4)
        eventArray.append(event)
        eventTitle.text = eventArray[0].title
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not creating some `Struct`?
Simple like this:

```
struct Event {
   var title: String
   var location: String
   var lat: CLLocationDegrees
   var long: CLLocationDegrees
}
```

Then just do that:

```
var eventArray = [Event]()
```

And call it like that:

```
for event in eventArray{
  event.title = eventTitle.text
}
```

Comment: This has the same problem as the code in the question. `eventArray` is an array and it has no `title` property.

Comment: If he want only one event he can do this: `var eventArray = Event()`, he will need anyway to make some array with indexes if he want more then one event, but in this way it will be easier to restore the data in another class.